# Copy to clipboard from datagridview

Tags: c#

Does anyone know why the following code is copy the selected cell value from a datagridview right with a button click and when I use this part under my custom contextMenuStrip it doesn't work? And most strange is that when I copy a checkbox cell it is working, when you paste this value you get "true"

See GIF image.[image: c]

Button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
  {
    try
    {
      // Add the selection to the clipboard.
      Clipboard.SetDataObject(
      dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)
    {
       //..
    }
  }
}
```

ContextMenuStrip:

```
private void cutctrlXToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
  {
    try
    {
      // Add the selection to the clipboard.
      Clipboard.SetDataObject(
      dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)
    {
       //..
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    {
      dgvCell.Value = string.Empty;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems that you are trying to copy a null value, have you tried to debug your program?

Comment: Debugging is not working on my computer because it's a Revit App. And this Revit version doesn't start when you want to debug

Comment: dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was because of this line that was activating the combobox in the datagrid by a first click (instead of two)

```
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

When delete this part it is working. To solve the first click of a combobox I added this part:

```
private void datagridview_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bool validClick = (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1); //Make sure the clicked row/column is valid.
    var datagridview = sender as DataGridView;

    // Check to make sure the cell clicked is the cell containing the combobox 
    if(datagridview.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn && validClick)
    {
        datagridview.BeginEdit(true);
        ((ComboBox)datagridview.EditingControl).DroppedDown = true;
    }
}
```